# Why do I need to use mut when the variable is never reassigned?

Tags: rust

I thought I understood when and why I need to use `mut` in Rust code, but I don't understand why I need to use `mut` in the following code.

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng(); // Why does this need to be mutable?
    println!("{:?}", rng); // outputs ThreadRng { rng: UnsafeCell }

    let x: u32 = rng.gen();
    println!("{}", x);

    println!("{:?}", rng); // outputs the same result as ThreadRng { rng: UnsafeCell }
}
```

Let me explain. The variable `rng` is declared mutable but its value never changes throughout the code, so why do I need to make `rng` variable mutable?

Comment: Generating a random number mutates the generators internal state.

Comment: *This line of code is not relevant to this post* -- obviously it is, since if you remove the two lines so marked, `rng` does not need to be marked mutable anymore! The error message when you remove `mut` even points directly at the spot where mutability is needed, on line 7.

Comment: Is generating a random number the only case we need `mut` or are there other cases where we need to add `mut` even though the value never changes?

Comment: Why do you assume the value never changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this question arises from the difference in the concept of "variable" in Rust from that in managed languages like Python or Java. In Python, there is an implicit indirection between variable and the object it holds, so:

```py
n = 42
n += 1         # the variable changed, but not the value (here immutable)

# however:
l = []
l.append(42)   # the value changed, but not the variable
l = [1, 2, 3]  # the variable changed, but not the value
```

In the second part, the variable `l` refers to a list object that exists independently of the variable. That object contains both the list elements and the metainformation such as list size. `l.append(42)` mutates the list object, while `l = [1, 2, 3]` mutates the variable to refer to a different (freshly created) list object. Multiple variables can easily refer to the same object, which can be a source of bugs.

Languages like Rust and C++ don't work like that. There is no implicit indirection between a variable and the value it contains, variables store the actual value. (Indirections can still exist, but they are either explicit using `Box` and `Rc` or hidden in the implementation of the object, as is the case with `Vec`, but are never provided by the language, they always have to be explicitly requested.) And two variables cannot contain the same object, because the object *is* the variable. For example:

```
let mut n = 42;
n += 1;             // the contents of the variable changed

// but also:
let mut l = vec![];
l.push(42);         // the contents of the variable changed
l = vec![1, 2, 3];  // the contents of the variable changed
```

In other words, the data that comprises the vector (the triple of <ptr, len, capacity>) is stored in-line **in the variable**, so every mutation of the vector counts as a modification of the variable. For example, when you append an element to the vector, the vector's length will change, so a piece of data stored directly in `l` will actually get modified. The only difference between invoking a `mut` method on `l` and assigning to `l` is that in the case of assignment, all fields are likely to change at once. But there is no fundamental difference between the two like there is in Python - both have the effect of modifying the contents stored in the variable. Since variables don't refer to independently-existing objects, the two types of mutation are indistinguishable as far as the language is concerned.

The same applies to the `rng` variable: it holds an RNG instance whose state must change when you generate the next number. This state change counts as change to the variable, just as does assigning it a brand new RNG. A value in Rust doesn't have inherent "identity" which would distinguish the assignment from other kinds of mutation to the state.

If you wanted to emulate the Python semantics, you could use a smart pointer:

```
// doesn't need to be mutable, holds reference to heap-allocated RNG
let rng = Rc::new(RefCell::new(thread_rng()));

// RefCell::borrow_mut() grants permission to mutate the shared object,
// but `rng` (the Rc pointer) is still unchanged
let x: u32 = rng.borrow_mut().gen();

// as expected, this wouldn't compile because rng is not mut:
//rng = Rc::new(RefCell::new(thread_rng()));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was what I was looking for. Especially the last part where you explain that the state change counts as change to the variable and a value in Rust doesn't have inherent "identity" which would distinguish the assignment from other kinds of mutation to the state. That's what I needed to hear. Also thank you for posting the alternative way by using `borrow_mut()`. It was useful too.

Comment: @tet Glad to hear it helped! Python forums in the late 90s were full of explanations in the other direction. :) In C++ a function argument is either passed by _value_, in which case a deep copy is made (akin to Rust's `.clone()`), or by _reference_, in which case the parameter variable just points to the caller's value. Python's model in which assignments are local to the function, but object mutations are still observable by the caller was a stumbling block for many. I find it ironic that now the Python/Java/Lisp model is the mainstream, and the Rust/C++/Pascal way is somewhat of an outlier.

Comment: @user4815162342 You are master of teaching! I still use C++ way of thinking even writing my everyday Python code, I just "see" all Python variables as references and I am really obsessed with immutability for objects thereof. And I really didn't understand which part of my explanation isn't understandable.

Comment: @tet You need to understand that Rust uses "value mutability semantics" even with indirection. E.g. you cannot modify readonly `Vec` element even if it does change only indirected object. It need to be explicitly mutable vector variable. Only exception is interior mutability pattern https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html which all build on top of UnsafeCell https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros The problem with seeing variables as references is that it doesn't translate for C++-style references; that mental model would fail to explain why `def foo(l): l = []` fails to clear `some_list` when invoked as `some_list = [1, 2, 3]; foo(some_list)`. I've seen it described that "object references are passed by value", but that only makes sense _after_ you've already understood the issue. (And for some reason this discussion appears to only exist for Python, although Java, C# or Lisp have the exact same argument-passing semantics, at least for class instances.)

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 cases when you need to declare variable as mutable:

1. When you change it value by assignment (you likely to already understand this):

```rust
let mut my_var = 5i32;
println!("old value {}", my_var);
my_var = my_var * 2;
println!("old value {}", my_var);
```

2. When you get mutable reference to it:

```rust
let mut my_var = 5i32;
println!("old value {}", my_var);
let reference = &mut my_var;
*reference = 10; // Mutable reference allow us change the value
println!("old value {}", my_var);
```

In code above would be quite surprising because if we declare `my_var`  as `let my_var`  because it's actual value changes.

Your case is exactly it. You call this method: https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen
Your code can be rephrased as:

```rust
let x: u32 = Rng::gen(&mut rng);
```

As you see, you take a mutable reference here by calling a method which uses `&mut self`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually understand why the `my_var` variable's value changes into 10 because of dereference in your second example. As of the rephrased code, I would understand if the value of `rng` changed after using `let x: u32 = Rng::gen(&mut rng);` and this is what I don't understand. Why does the `rng` variable need to be mutable if the value of `rng` never changes?

Comment: @tet but `Rng::gen` does change the value of `rng`!

Comment: @tet Implementations of Rng trait change their internal state. For example, this code called in `Rng::gen`: https://github.com/rust-random/rngs/blob/eae0a9b91c5de272706134d25bc1ea3457bc9670/rand_xoshiro/src/common.rs#L149 As you see, it overwrites values of struct fields.

Comment: @tet *Why does the rng variable need to be mutable if the value of `rng` never changes?* - It's not true that the value of `rng` never changes, but I think I understand where the confusion might be coming from. I added an answer meant to supplement this one that specifically addresses that point.